# RabbitMQ service when stopping and installing the services

Tags: powershell, rabbitmq

I have a PowerShell script where I have the following code

```
$Rabbit_Path = "C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.6"
$RabbitMQ_service=Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='RabbitMQ'" | Select-Object;

if($RabbitMQ_service.status -eq "OK" -and $RabbitMQ_service.state -ne "Stopped")
{ 
  & $Rabbit_Path\sbin\rabbitmq-service.bat stop 
  & $Rabbit_Path\sbin\rabbitmq-service.bat remove
}

& $Rabbit_Path\sbin\rabbitmq-service.bat install
& $Rabbit_Path\sbin\rabbitmq-service.bat start
```

This works fine one the first instance but when I am executing the same I am getting an exception like unable to start the service so can some one help me

Comment: Which line is producing the error?

Comment: And what does the error say exactly?

Comment: `rabbitmq-service.bat : C:\Program Files\erl8.0\erts-8.0\bin\erlsrv: Failed to start service RabbitMQ. Error: The process terminated unexpectedly.`

Comment: `& $Rabbit_Path\sbin\rabbitmq-service.bat start` this is producing error

Comment: What are the values of `.status` and `.state` when the error occurs?

Comment: both are getting same as per written `state` will be in running

Comment: I am installing RabbitMQ from PowerShell script so this is working fine when I run it for first time. But if I am executing the same script for second time I am getting the issue

Comment: *"both are getting same as per written `state` will be in running"* I don't understand what that's supposed to mean.

Comment: When I install, `status` is in `OK` and `state` is in `Running`

Comment: When you run the script for the second time?